# Open Graph GIF size for preview in iMessage

Tags: facebook-opengraph, imessage

Is there a specific size limit for Open Graph image preview(gif in this case) for a URL in iMessage?  It seems like some of my smaller GIFs will load, where as the others just show a URL w/ no preview even though I have verified the correct property for og:image has been set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed Apple has a limit on how big icon and image/video may be combined. The limit is 10 MB as stated in this video [Apples video on rich links in iMessage](http://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/205/).

Answer (score 0):

The limit is as specified by Apple is 10 MB for all og: items combined(photo & icon).